# Change logo on navigation bar onscroll in striking multiflex theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, navigationbar, onscrollchanged

I want to change the logo on navigation bar when i scroll the page down.I am using a wordpress 'Striking Multiflex theme" installed

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery $(window).scroll() event handler

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        var height = $(window).height();
        var url = 'url to new image';
        if(height > 100){
           $('.site-logo').attr('src',url);  
        }

    })
```